# Table not creating while installing a custom module in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, database

I am creating a simple module. In that module I need to save the values in a table and I have created an .install file to create the table when the module is installed.

While installing the module, it is not creating the table and it gives a PDOException Error. I am unable to find the issue with my code.

The error message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT ' AMOUNT', `rate` unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'R' at line 3: CREATE TABLE {sampletest} ( `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'My unique identifier', `amount` unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'AMOUNT', `rate` unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT ' RATE', `time` unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '  TIME', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT ' table'; Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2717 of H:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\includes\database\database.inc) ;

Content of the .install file :

```
<?php
/**
* Implements hook_install().
*/
function sampletest_install() {
 drupal_install_schema('sampletest');
}
/**
* Implements hook_install().
*/
function sampletest_uninstall() {
  drupal_uninstall_schema('sampletest');
}
/**
* Implements hook_schema().
*/

function sampletest_schema() {
  $schema['sampletest'] = array(
    'description' => t('EMI table'),
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => t('My unique identifier'),
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => true,
        'not null' => true,
      ),
      'amount' => array(
        'description' => t('AMOUNT'),
        'type' => 'bigint',
        'unsigned' => true,
        'not null' => true,
      ),
      'rate' => array(
        'description' => t('RATE'),
        'type' => 'bigint',
        'unsigned' => true,
        'not null' => true,
      ),
      'time' => array(
        'description' => t('TIME'),
        'type' => 'bigint',
        'unsigned' => true,
        'not null' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
  );
  return $schema;     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 problems with in your code:

1. You should not call `drupal_install_schema()` from `hook_install()` in Drupal 7. `hook_schema()` will be called and the table will be automatically created/dropped on installing/uninstalling. See here: https://drupal.org/node/224333#install-schema
2. As [@Ollie](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/106370/10176) also stated, there's no field type named `bigint`. You should use `int` and set its size to `big`.

Like following:

```
'amount' => array(
  'description' => t('Amount'),
  'type' => 'int',
  'size' => 'big',
  'unsigned' => TRUE,
  'not null' => TRUE,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in using 'bigint' as the type. Use 'type'=>'int', 'size'=>'big', instead.

Comment: And are you sure your 'id' shouldn't be of type serial (auto-increment)?